# Complicated COUNTIFS formula with unique values

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a spreadsheet used to produce a daily report with column A being the company name, column b the employee's name and column c being the employee's position. The ultimate goal is to have a tally of how many people from the same company worked that day.

However, I have now run into the issue of if an employee works multiple positions in the same day(Emily Anne of XYZ Limited in the example spreadsheet), they are double counted.

[image: Sample worksheet]

To count the employees at the same company, I have used countifs formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A20,"ABC Company",D2:D20,">0")
```

as it is possible certain employees don't work on a specific day. But i am not sure what formula to use to make sure employees who work more than one position in a day aren't double counted. Looking for help with a formula that can still help me tally employees but only count the occurrence of a name once. Below is an example of what my spreadsheet looks like with some dummy data.

Answer (score 2):

Try using : <kbd>SUMPRODUCT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(((G2=$A$2:$A$20)*($D$2:$D$20>0))/
  COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$20,$A$2:$A$20,$B$2:$B$20,$B$2:$B$20,$D$2:$D$20,">0"),0))
```

---

Or, use <kbd>SUMPRODUCT()</kbd> with <kbd>IF()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF((G2=$A$2:$A$20)*($D$2:$D$20>0),
  1/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$20,$A$2:$A$20,$B$2:$B$20,$B$2:$B$20),0))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=LET(
    a,A2:A20,
    b,B2:B20,
    c,D2:D20,
    ua,UNIQUE(a),
    HSTACK(ua,BYROW(ua,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(b,(x=a)*(c>0),""))<>""))))))
```

---

Comment: Formulas look good to me. I think that B8 is meant to be Emily Anne the same as B9 so that is a duplicate name and should only be counted once giving a total of 4 for XYZ limited.

Comment: @TomSharpe Sir, correct, I think the `y` is missing, i have used `Excel` Image Tool to convert the screenshot, will change it now. Thanks Sir