# Complicated COUNTIFS formula with unique values: Part 2

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, countif

I had asked this question previously and got a response that worked. However, as of this morning, the solution no longer works and I cant figure out why.

[Previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77390475/complicated-countifs-formula-with-unique-values/77390533#77390533)

Looking for help with a formula that can help tally employees but only count the occurrence of a name once. I do not want a double count if an employee works multiple positions in the same day(Emily Anne of ABC Company in the example spreadsheet). Additionally, I do not want an employee counted if they didn't work that day (ex. Dave Smith with 0 hours)

I used the formula provided by Mayukh Bhattacharya:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((("FORWARD"=$A3:$A$28)*($M$3:$M$28>0))/
  COUNTIFS($A3:$A$28,$A3:$A$28,$I$3:$I$28,$I$3:$I$28,$M$3:$M$28,">0"),0))
```

However now instead of producing the correct count, the formula in J1 now produces 0.

[image: Example spreadsheet]

Comment: There is no Company in column A called "FORWARD" ...

Comment: Also as @Ike madam, highlighted I have not given you a formula which reflects the word `FORWARD` could you shed some light from where you are getting the word

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya the word "FORWARD" was a typo. It is the actual company name I forgot to remove from the formula when trying to make the dummy data. It seems the issue was with my version of excel. I used CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and it is back to working. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason where the formula is not working, even when changing the word `"FORWARD"` to `ABC Company`

[image]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF((M3:M28>0)*(A3:A28="ABC Company"),
  1/COUNTIFS(A3:A28,"ABC Company",E3:E28,E3:E28,M3:M28,">0"),0))
```

---

Or, Using old formula given.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((("ABC Company"=$A$3:$A$28)*($E$3:$E$28>0))/
  COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$28,$A$3:$A$28,$E$3:$E$28,$E$3:$E$28,$M$3:$M$28,">0"),0))
```

---

Or, Using dynamic array formulas:

```
=SUM(N(TAKE(UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(A3:N28,(A3:A28="ABC Company")*(M3:M28>0)),1,5)),,1)<>""))
```

---

Reference to last post: **[Solutions in last post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77390533/8162520)**

---

**Note:** If using older version of excel then make sure to hit the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

---